# Relative cohomology on manifolds with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm studying this paper "[Cohomology of Harmonic Forms on Riemannian Manifolds With Boundary](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508372.pdf)".

At the bottom of page 4, it says "$CcC^p_N$ is the orthogonal complement of the exact $p$-forms within the closed ones, so $CcC^p_N \cong H^p(M;\mathbb{R})$". This is straightforward by the definition of cohomology.

Then it says "$CcC^p_D$ is the orthogonal complement of the co-exact $p$-forms within the co-closed ones, so $CcC^p_D \cong H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$". My understanding is that the co-closed $p$-forms modulo the co-exact $p$-forms gives $H^p(M;\mathbb{R})$, which is isomorphic to $H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$ by the Poincaré–Lefschetz duality, so we have $CcC^p_D \cong H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$.

Is my understanding correct? If so, why not just saying $CcC^p_D \cong H^p(M;\mathbb{R})$? In other words, what's the point of bringing up the relative cohomology $H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You’re misquoting duality, no? The paper asserts that the Dirichlet condition yields the relative cohomology, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin The paper says "$CcC^p_D$ is the orthogonal complement of the co-exact $p$-forms within the co-closed ones, so $CcC^p_D \cong H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$", I don't get why the orthogonal complement of the co-exact $p$-forms within the co-closed ones is isomorphic to $H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$. I thought it's due to the the Poincaré–Lefschetz duality, which doesn't seem right, so could you please elaborate why $CcC^p_D \cong H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$? Thanks.

Comment: You’re missing the Dirichlet condition. What’s the definition of relative deRham  cohomology? I am not sure about the co here …

Comment: @TedShifrin $H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$ is the cohomology of $M$ mod $\partial M$, right? And the co is precisely what I'd like to know: how are co-exact and co-closed forms related to $H^p(M, \partial M;\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: No, not $M$ mod $\partial M$ at all. Look up the chain complexes. This is in Spivak, Vol 1, as I recall. The Dirichlet condition is super important.