# Could a differential form be both exact and co-exact?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-forms, manifolds-with-boundary, hodge-theory

If my understanding is correct, on a closed manifold, the exact forms and co-exact forms are disjoint, but I'm not sure about the differential forms on manifolds with boundary. Could there be a differential form that is both exact and co-exact on a manifold with boundary? I'm particularly interested in 2D manifolds with boundary (i.e. surfaces with boundary).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a manifold with boundary.

Comment: So you didn’t take a moment to think why I asked you the question. Maybe you should.

Comment: Plenty of 2-dimensional manifolds with boundary — both compact and not — are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm thinking about 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\beta = d\alpha = \delta \gamma$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are 0-form, 1-form, 2-form, respectively. So we have $d\alpha - \delta \gamma = 0$, then $ \delta d\alpha = d\delta \gamma = 0$, thus $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ being harmonic forms is a necessary condition for $\beta$ be an exact and co-exact 1-form in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this correct? What about the sufficient conditions, which I don't know how to derive?

Comment: With regard to your original question, [this paper](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/papers/har-coho-7.pdf)  should be of interest. For the noncompact case, you might search for results on $L^2$ harmonic forms on complete Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the reference. I think it comes down to the decomposition under Eq. (1): $CcC^p = CcC^p_N \bigoplus EcC^p = CcC^p_D \bigoplus CcE^p$, so if a closed & co-closed form $\omega \in CcC^p$ doesn't satisfy the Dirichlet boundary condition ($\omega \notin CcC^p_D$) or the Neumann boundary condition ($\omega \notin CcC^p_N$), then we have $\omega \in EcC^p$ and $\omega \in CcE^p$, thus $\omega$ is exact and co-exact (and closed and co-closed). Is this right?

Comment: @TedShifrin I actually studied the paper you referred before as I asked a question regarding that paper [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512258/relative-cohomology-on-manifolds-with-boundary), but I haven't received any response yet, so do you mind taking a look? Thanks.